# modal views not working when compiling in xcode 4

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, xcode4, modalviewcontroller

I've just updated to Xcode 4 had a few problems getting the app to compile but they are sorted now. However I have a major problem with the navigation of my app. I have various buttons that all fire actions that should display different modal windows using code similar to the following

```
- (IBAction)showMyJobs:(id)sender {
    UIViewController *myJobsView = [[MyJobsView alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyJobsView" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:myJobsView];
    [self presentModalViewController:navigationController animated:YES];
    [myJobsView release];
}
```

Now all this code was working perfectly before I compiled the app in xcode 4. What happens now is that the code seems to run (see it running in the debugger) but nothing gets displayed. Can anyone point me in the right direction as to whats going on.

I don't get any errors/warnings while compiling, nothing. It's driving me mad!

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: have you tried a clean build?

Comment: Yeah tried that many times :)

Answer (score 0):

Just a stab in the dark, but try:

```
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:navigationController animated:YES];
```

Comment: Thanks Alex. Unfortunately it had no effect. I can see the UIViewController and UINavigationController getting created in the debugger while stepping through, but still does nothing when it gets to presentModalViewController.

Answer (score 0):

This is really late, but for what its worth - you need to release the navigation controller first and then the view controller.